# Insert Into Table B Select * From Table A, but with an extra column in Table B, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have Table A and Table B. Table A has columns A, B and C and Table B has columns A, B, C **and D**.

If I do the following:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT * FROM Table A
WHERE (....)
```

Will it allow me to do it, even with the extra column that the Table B has? I'm trying to do this in my project, however, they told me that the Table B should have the same columns as Table A but with an extra one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case when columns are not the same in both tables you have to explicitly specify columns in insert and select statements.

So in your particular case it should be

```
INSERT INTO TableB (A, B, C)
SELECT A, B, C FROM Table A
WHERE (....)
```

Otherwise, if you're not specifying columns in insert statement, it is supposed in most DBMS that columns should be taken from table definition, and in your case it looks like `INSERT INTO TableB (A, B, C, D)` - and assumes 4 columns, but `SELECT * FROM Table A` will generate only 3 columns instead of 4. This is the reason of error you're getting.

Comment: So I can't do it like this? INSERT INTO TableB (A, B, C) SELECT * FROM Table A

Comment: In the case when columns order in tables A and B is the same, you can use query you've mentioned, since in this case key feature - is that insert should affect only three columns. But I recommend you always use explicit columns specification since it can protect you from some unwanted results (for example, if some columns in tables A and B will be swapped, say A, B, C in A and A, C, B in B - in this case `insert ... select * ...` will produce some unexpected result).

Answer (score 0):

You should specify to which columns of Table B the values from Table A will be inserted. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (col1 INT, col2 INT);
INSERT INTO foo
VALUES (1,2);

CREATE TABLE bar (col1 INT,col2 INT, col3 INT);
INSERT INTO bar (col1,col2)
SELECT * FROM foo
```

will do exactly what you want.